# How to add a semi transparent box over an image and aligned to the right?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a semi transparent text box over an image, the box needs to be aligned to the right, and have not got a clue how to do it, can anyone help?

I have mocked the page up here: http://dev.gigiscucina.co.uk/, screenshot below. The red blocks are just place holders.

[image]

The HTML is below. I want to be able to add a semi transparent text block on home_widget_2 (text right aligned) and home home_widget_4 (text left aligned).

```
<div id="home_widget_1" class="grid col-300">
    <div id="text-2" class="widget-wrapper widget_text">            
        <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://dev.gigiscucina.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/300.jpg" alt= ""></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of .col-300 -->

<div id="home_widget_2" class="grid col-620 fit">
    <div id="text-3" class="widget-wrapper widget_text">            
        <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://dev.gigiscucina.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/620.jpg" alt= ""></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of .col-620 fit -->

<div id="home_widget_3" class="grid col-620">
    <div id="text-4" class="widget-wrapper widget_text">            
        <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://dev.gigiscucina.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/620.jpg" alt= ""></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of .col-620 -->

<div id="home_widget_4" class="grid col-300 fit">
    <div id="text-5" class="widget-wrapper widget_text">            
        <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://dev.gigiscucina.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/300.jpg" alt= ""></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of .col-300 fit -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box { 
   position: relative; 
   width:300px;
}

.box p { 
   position: absolute; 
   bottom: 0; 
   right: 0; 
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   color:#ffffff;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="image.png" width="300" alt="" />
    <p>this is where your text will go<br />change image size according to div width</p>
</div>
```